# Module Based Development in Nette php

Tags: php, nette

My question is pretty simple.I an developing a web site using Nette framework.can I use a module based project structure.
Ex:
Project
  |- app
       |- Module_1
       |- Module_2

Answer (score 0):

You can. See [official documentation](https://doc.nette.org/en/2.2/presenters#toc-modules) for more information.